# Why am I able to create MV logs using PK — even though there is no PK?

Tags: oracle, primary-key, logs, materialized-view, oracle-19c

I have a table that does **not** have a primary key:

[image]

---

I'm able to create MV logs on the table — without specifying whether to use the primary key or the rowid:

```
create materialized view log on maximo.workorder;
```

It looks like Oracle has chosen to create the MV logs using the **primary key** option (even though the table doesn't have a primary key):

[image]

I've tested the MV logs and they **are working correctly**. Any edits that I make to the WORKORDER table  are showing up in the MV logs.

---

Why is it possible for Oracle to create the MV logs using the primary key option — even though the table doesn't have a primary key?

---

**Edit:**

Related question here: [Create fast-refresh MV over dblink on table without PK?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280854/create-fast-refresh-mv-over-dblink-on-table-without-pk)

Comment: I don't know for certain that this is the case, but perhaps when there is not a primary key present in the table, Oracle automatically uses some type of automatically generated row id instead.  Perhaps the `ROWID` [pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)

Comment: Can you add the actual table DDL and rows from `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` `WHERE TABLE_NAME='WORKORDER'`?

Comment: @mustaccio You'll have to excuse my ignorance. I'm not a dba, so I don't have access to `DBA_CONSTRAINTS`. But I **do** have access to `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`. I performed this query `select * from all_constraints where table_name='WORKORDER' and owner = 'MAXIMO' `. ... And I've shared it as a WITH/query on db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cc8d25819af83330ef8f1b61d7ac90b8. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @mustaccio Please bear in mind that the database is a COTS product from IBM. I didn't design the table and don't have much flexibility when it comes to altering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unique constraint on a `NOT NULL` column (which you have, as I checked this table in a database where Maximo was installed) is a good enough substitute for a primary key in this case.

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 number, c2 number);

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view log on t1;
create materialized view log on t1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12014: table 'T1' does not contain a primary key constraint

SQL> alter table t1 add unique(c1);

Table altered.

SQL> create materialized view log on t1;
create materialized view log on t1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12014: table 'T1' does not contain a primary key constraint

SQL> alter table t1 modify c1 not null;

Table altered.

SQL> create materialized view log on t1;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> select master, primary_key from user_mview_logs;

MASTER                         PRI
------------------------------ ---
T1                             YES
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see some documentation on what the criteria is for columns that are"good enough" to be primary keys for MV logs.